# Using Typedia to Classify a Font Collection

Tags: fonts

So this might be a long-shot.

[Typedia](http://typedia.com) is a encyclopedia for fonts.

[Fontcase](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/fontcase/) is a font management program.

Fontcase uses the Typedia database to classify fonts (serif, display, sans-serif, etc.) using tags and genres and stuff.

This is really cool, but I don't want to use Fontcase. I prefer FontExplorer X Pro. Classifying fonts manually is a pain and can take hours upon hours. Is there any way of using this kind of functionality to other programs?

Comment: *Typedia*'s font classifications such as designer, country, year and distributor are custom made and such fields are not embedded in the font files themselves. Even for field like vendor name, it's not guaranteed that the field value is filled at the time the font file was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't seem like this is possible.